# Slow SELECT MySQL query inside SELECT

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

The following query is taking about 3.55 seconds to execute. It is obviously the subquery that is causing most of the problem, because when I run a similar query by itself it is taking 0.981 seconds. I have the tables indexed, so I'm not sure what I could be doing wrong. Any thoughts?

```
SELECT
    u.user_id,
    u.username,
    u.fullname,
    u.avatar,
    u.city,
    u.state,
 (
    SELECT
        COUNT(*) AS total_followers
    FROM
        FollowerRelationship fr
    WHERE
        fr.user_id = u.user_id
    GROUP BY
        fr.user_id
) AS total
FROM
    Users u
ORDER BY
    total DESC
```

Comment: Sounds like you need an index: `ALTER TABLE FollowerRelationship ADD INDEX user_id (user_id);`. BTW you can drop the GROUP BY since it is already filtered by user_id.

Comment: @Sal yeah I have indexes set up in both tables. If the query is built right, could it be an overall resource issue with the server?

Comment: Maybe. An explain plan would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You are joining the subquery in your select clause on the contents on the 'outside' of the sub query, which may be slowing things up. If your indexes are setup correctly, and `fr`.user_id is not nullable, then the join on your users table is not necessary since you are hitting the entire `FollowerRelationship` (which I am assuming since you need users to be followers) and `Users` table in both cases: the join doesnt change the amount of `COUNT`.

```
SELECT
    u.user_id,
    u.username,
    u.fullname,
u.avatar,
 u.city,
 u.state,
 (
    SELECT
        COUNT(*) AS total_followers
    FROM
        FollowerRelationship fr
    GROUP BY
        fr.user_id
) AS total
FROM
    Users u
ORDER BY
    total DESC
```

Alternatively, you could repeat the join inside the subquery, if you need it.